# Regular Expressions start with end with

Tags: regex

What is the Regular Expression to find statement in file? It starts with `--Source table` and end with `;`

Sample:

```
-- Source table: I_ZNACZNIKI_KONF
   CREATE TABLE test10."I_ZNACZNIKI_KONF" (
     "ID_ZNACZNIKA_KONF" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     "NAZWA" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
     "WYR_TECHN" CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL, 
     "OPIS" VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL
   ) WITH OIDS;

-- Source primary key: PK_I_ZNACZNIKI_KONF
   ALTER TABLE test10."I_ZNACZNIKI_KONF"
     ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_I_ZNACZNIKI_KONF" 
        PRIMARY KEY ("ID_ZNACZNIKA_KONF");
```

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: What is suppose to be found in your sample? `--Source table` doesn't exist in sample.

Comment: @chris85 look better, first statement starts with -- Source table. Next statement starts with --Source primary key. And i need to find only the statement which starts with -- Source table ends with ; without second statement

Comment: @YoFi Look at what you literally wrote. Note spacing. `-- Source table` != `--Source table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following regex pattern:

```
-- Source [^\n]+\n([^;]+);
```

https://regex101.com/r/MGEA2R/1

Comment: Thanks a lot, I needed smth like that: ^(-- Source primary key)+[^\n]+\n([^;]+);

Answer (score 0):

RegExp:

```
(\-[^;]+;)
```

Match: => $1

```
-- Source table: I_ZNACZNIKI_KONF
   CREATE TABLE test10."I_ZNACZNIKI_KONF" (
     "ID_ZNACZNIKA_KONF" INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     "NAZWA" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
     "WYR_TECHN" CHAR(1) DEFAULT 'N' NOT NULL, 
     "OPIS" VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL
   ) WITH OIDS;

-- Source primary key: PK_I_ZNACZNIKI_KONF
   ALTER TABLE test10."I_ZNACZNIKI_KONF"
     ADD CONSTRAINT "PK_I_ZNACZNIKI_KONF" 
        PRIMARY KEY ("ID_ZNACZNIKA_KONF");
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/TB7O4k/1